# Dynamically create a complex nested JSON based on values computed in runtime

Tags: python, json, dictionary, type-conversion, nested-loops

I am very new to python dictionaries and JSON. Basically i am working on a document summarization problem in which i require creation of the below JSON so I could render it in my UI.

The JSON structure I wish to generate dynamically is as below:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "filename": FileName,
      "extracted_Text": [
        {
          "Heading": MainHeading,
          "text": MainHeadingText,
          "Sub_Headings": [
            {
              "Heading": SubHeading,
              "text": SubHeadingText,
              "Sub_Headings": [
                {
                  "Heading": SubSubHeading,
                  "text": SubSubHeadingText,
                  "Sub_Headings": [
                    {
                      "Heading": SubSubSubHeading,
                      "text": SubSubSubHeadingText,
                      "Sub_Headings": [
                        
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The above sample contains only one file (for example), whereas I am required to get the results of multiple files and convert them in runtime.

The string values to be passed to Heading/Subheading/Text would have to be passed, which I have already computed and wish to pass them as variables to the JSON.
The nesting stops with SubSubSubHeading i.e. "1.1.1.1 Sample" and there will not be a Level 5.

I know I should use loops but as the structure is too complex for me with combination of list and dict, I am stuck. Kindly help me out. Cheers !!

UPDATE:

Below is an example of what needs to be stored in the JSON. This is upon passing two files and the amount of files passed would be dynamic. ( Values of variables i.e. Main Heading and Sub Heading are different at each level):

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "filename": "File 1.txt",
      "extracted_text": {
        "heading": "MAIN HEADING -1",
        "text": " Sample text under Main Heading",
        "sub_headings": {
          "heading": "SUB HEADING - 1",
          "text": "Sample text under Sub Heading",
          "sub_headings": {
            "heading": "SUB SUB HEADING - 1",
            "text": "Sample text under Sub Sub Heading",
            "sub_headings": {
              "heading": "SUB SUB SUB HEADING - 1",
              "text": "Sample text under Sub Sub Sub Heading",
              "sub_headings": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "filename": "File 2.txt",
      "extracted_text": {
        "heading": "MAIN HEADING -1",
        "text": " Sample text under Main Heading",
        "sub_headings": {
          "heading": "SUB HEADING - 1",
          "text": "Sample text under Sub Heading",
          "sub_headings": {
            "heading": "SUB SUB HEADING - 1",
            "text": "Sample text under Sub Sub Heading",
            "sub_headings": {
              "heading": "SUB SUB SUB HEADING - 1",
              "text": "Sample text under Sub Sub Sub Heading",
              "sub_headings": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is what the text file contains. I extract 1,2,3 in a list and pass it to key 'heading', extract 1.1 and pass to the first nexted Sub-heading and so on.

```
1 Main Heading-1 
1.1 Sub Heading-1  
2 Main Heading-2  
2.1 Sub Heading-1  
2.1.1 SubSub Heading-1  
2.1.2 SubSub Heading-2  
2.1.2.1 SubSubSub Heading-1  
3 Main Heading-3
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of the data you have that needs to be transformed into the above `dict`?

Comment: That's not very easy to see in a comment. Can you update your question?

Comment: No, not really. Now you have your `dict` you can just use `json.dump()` to write it to a file.

Comment: More than creatign the JSON, making it dynamic and flexible to accept any number of files (above update has two) with differing "values" to the "keys" would require loops, which is confusing

Comment: I'm asking where this data comes from. I can see your `dict` above, but how does that relate to things like `2.1.2.1 SubSubSub Heading`?

Comment: The variable values are extracted from a text file. In the update, I showed a sample representation of what the final JSON is expected to look like with the extracted values plugged in.

Comment: Ok, so please update the question with some sample data from the text file.

Comment: That's not very easy to see in a comment. Can you update your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the dictonaries in Python you can convert to JSON with `json.dump`.
Since your `sub_headings` field seems to be nested, you can use a loop to created the nested dictionary as follows:

```
import json

# create nested sub_headings
depth = 4
sub_headings = ""
for i in range(depth):
    sub_headings = {'heading':"",
                    'text':"",
                    'sub_headings':sub_headings}

# create results dictionary
results = {'filename':"",
           'extracted_text':sub_headings}

# store in dictionary
my_dictionary = {'results':results}

# parse dictionary to JSON:
my_json = json.dumps(my_dictionary)

# View the resulting JSON:
print(my_json)
```

Comment: But won't the above just iterate the variable value of sub_heading multiple times ? Please consider that there are differing values for headings and sub-heading at each level .... i.e. 1 "Main Heading-1", 1.1 "Sub Heading-1", 2 "Main Heading-2", 2.1 "Sub Heading-1", 2.1.1 "SubSub Heading-1", 2.1.2 "SubSub Heading-2", 2.1.2.1 "SubSubSub Heading-1", 3 "Main Heading-3".. which would be passed dynamically and this is for just one file

Comment: Well, yeah, that was how your question was originally stated.  
Anyway, it's a for loop, you can make it as funky as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your hierarchical data can be transformed by a recursive algorithm.

I have created `"headings.txt"`:

```
1 Main Heading-1 
1.1 Sub Heading-1  
2 Main Heading-2  
2.1 Sub Heading-1  
2.1.1 SubSub Heading-1  
2.1.2 SubSub Heading-2  
2.1.2.1 SubSubSub Heading-1  
3 Main Heading-3
```

And this code reads that file and creates a list which should be similar to the list `"extracted_Text"` in your first snippet of an example `dict`:

```py
def update(text, n, txt):
    n0 = int(n[0])
    while len(text) < n0:
        text.append({"Heading":'', "text":'', "Sub_Headings":[]})
    d0 = text[n0-1]
    if len(n) == 1:
        d0["Heading"] = txt
    else:
        update(d0["Sub_Headings"], n[1:], txt)
        
text = []
with open("headings.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        ls = line.strip()
        ns,txt = ls.split(' ', 1)
        n = ns.split('.')
        update(text,n,txt)

print(text)
```

Output:

```py
[
    {
        "Heading": "Main Heading-1",
        "text": "",
        "Sub_Headings": [
            {
                "Heading": "Sub Heading-1",
                "text": "",
                "Sub_Headings": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Heading": "Main Heading-2",
        "text": "",
        "Sub_Headings": [
            {
                "Heading": "Sub Heading-1",
                "text": "",
                "Sub_Headings": [
                    {
                        "Heading": "SubSub Heading-1",
                        "text": "",
                        "Sub_Headings": []
                    },
                    {
                        "Heading": "SubSub Heading-2",
                        "text": "",
                        "Sub_Headings": [
                            {
                                "Heading": "SubSubSub Heading-1",
                                "text": "",
                                "Sub_Headings": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Heading": "Main Heading-3",
        "text": "",
        "Sub_Headings": []
    }
]
```